# MySQL error code 1005 errno -1

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I am trying to forward engineer a Workbench database like I have been doing. This time was different though, instead of working normally it gave me a strange error.

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~' (errno: -1)
```

I tried searching what errno -1 was but no luck. Anyone have a clue what this error message is trying to tell me?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`User` (

`Uid` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`Username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

`Password` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,

`Avatar` TINYTEXT NULL ,

`Status` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active' COMMENT 'Active, Warned, Banned' ,

 PRIMARY KEY (`Uid`) )

  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

There are other parts to it but it can't even get past ANY table creation. Also changed DB name, quite sure I spelled it correctly.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the error lies in the name of the table. (Unless `~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~` wasn't the real name.)

Comment: PL post your create table code.

Comment: Posted one of my table creates that doesn't work, well none work with this strange error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply removed the `database.` and run your query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab9a8/1) and it works:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (

`Uid` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

`Username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,

`Password` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,

`Avatar` TINYTEXT NULL ,

`Status` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active' COMMENT 'Active, Warned, Banned' ,

 PRIMARY KEY (`Uid`) )

  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Give a look at [InnoDB Error Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html) as it says:

```
Error 1005 (ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE)

Cannot create table. If the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed.
If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table.
```

Comment: I tried that, still same error. However after deleting the database I think it might be a corrupted database. I deleted the database, tried to re-add it but it says it is still there...

Comment: Yup the new database works just fine.

Comment: @Rujikin Edited the answer with further details.

Comment: See those links for more help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html